# Wordpress and DB files when using Docker in Windows

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I've run a container with docker-compose following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) Docker page, that use this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

The point is, I want to connect to a local database and needs to change the default DB connection from MySQL to a PostgreSQL DB. I've used the docker environment variables, setting the WORDPRESS_DB_HOST/USER/PASSWORD/NAME in wordpress section, but in the end Wordpress states that connection can't be established.

And I want to create my own Wordpress theme but I don't know where the folder is created to put the theme files there.

Any help will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have the [Postgres Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) running (assuming you're wanting to also run that as a Docker image, and not installed directly on your machine), you'll need to get it all set up first so you know all of it's settings that you'll need.

After that, you'll need to edit your `dockerfile` to look something to this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: postgres
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/postgres
     restart: always
     environment:
       <the environment vars for postres>

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Regarding where to place your custom theme(s), it should be in your `my_wordpress_wordpress_1` volume (or whichever one it automatically created. I don't have WP installed in a docker machine so I don't know firsthand how they place the data in that volume, but typically WP's file tree looks like this: `wp-content\themes`